# How to convert MSSQL Sever Table to a better XML format?

Tags: sql, xml, select, path

How can I convert a MSSQL 2012 table (#myTable) like this:

```
name|lastname|child1|age1|child2|age2|child3|age3| prnt|prnt2
Jack|Jones   |Jill  |2   |Joe   |4   |Mike  |5   | Mark| Lizy
```

to XML format like this:

```
<familyTree>
    <firstname> Jack </firstname>
    <lastname> Jones </lastname>
    <babies>
        <baby> Jill </baby>
        <old> 2 </old> 
    <babies>
    <babies>
        <baby> Joe </baby>
        <old> 4 </old> 
    <babies>
   <babies>
        <baby> Mike </baby>
        <old> 5 </old> 
    <babies>
    <father>Mark </father>
    <mother>lizy </mother>
</familyTree>
```

A select statement like this:

```
SELECT 
    name         AS "firstname",
    lastname     AS "lastname",
    child1       AS "babies/baby",
    age1         AS "babies/old",
    child2       AS "babies/baby",
    age2         AS "babies/old",
    child3       AS "babies/baby",
    age3         AS "babies/old",
    prnt         AS "father",
    prnt2        AS "mother"
FROM  #myTable 
         FOR XML PATH('familyTree')
```

would result in:

```
<familyTree>
    <firstname> Jack </firstname>
    <lastname> Jones </lastname>
    <babies>
        <baby> Jill </baby>
        <old> 2 </old> 
        <baby> Joe </baby>
        <old> 4 </old> 
        <baby> Mike </baby>
        <old> 5 </old> 
    <babies>
    <father>Mark </father>
    <mother>lizy </mother>
</familyTree>
```

This structure is not the same as the desired structure given above. Any help or step in right direction would be appreciated? thank you in advance.

Comment: Which database vendor?  Many have built in features for xml rendering of relational data.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it. it's Microsoft SQL server 2012. I edited the header of the question. thanks.

Comment: I can understand the confusion.  Similarly, I understand why it does it that way.  Would you consider making the age an attribute of the baby?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421509/how-to-add-attributes-to-xml-nodes-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: Thanks Dan. unfortunately, it's not possible to change it to an attribute. it's supposed to be nested nodes as <baby> and <old> under <babies>. I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751131/sql-for-xml-path-nested-results but that's for reading rows and formatting them in nested format. I am trying to experiment with it. Maybe someone has already had a solution to this issue and shed some light on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the trick (in case someone in future tries to overcome the same situation).

```
SELECT 
    name         AS "firstname",
    lastname     AS "lastname",
    child1       AS "babies/baby",
    age1         AS "babies/old",
    '',
    child2       AS "babies/baby",
    age2         AS "babies/old",
    '',
    child3       AS "babies/baby",
    age3         AS "babies/old",
    prnt         AS "father",
    prnt2        AS "mother"
FROM  #myTable 
         FOR XML PATH('familyTree')
```